# Datetimepicker getting assigned to all the input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have four textboxes. They have the following id:-
`title`, `sdate`, `edate`, `pdate`.

I want Datetimepicker to be assigned for the texboxes which have the text 'date' in their id.

That means, I want want datetimepicker to be assigned to the three textboxes- `sdate`, `edate`, `pdate`.

Here is the code I am using-

```
$('[id*="date"]').each(function(){
   $(this).datetimepicker({
       formatTime:'H:i:s',
       formatDate:'Y-m-d',
       dayOfWeekStart : 1,
       lang:'en'
       //disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
       //startDate:  '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>'
   });  
});
```

I am having a strange problem. **All the Textboxes are getting assigned with DatetimePicker**. Why is that happening?

Note:- I am using the bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

### EDIT

The id of the form was `'validateForm'`. That's why it was taking the datetimepicker, and I thought the 'title' textbox is taking the Datetimepicker.

As suggested by Vinod, I am using this right now- `'input[id*="date"]'`

But this doesn't work sure for input elements like `file` or `submit` having id containing the string `'date'`.

How can I work on that?

Comment: why not use ("#sdate, #edate, #pdate") ? I guess * is doing some trick else try ^

Comment: Actually, I am trying to create a code-snippet where any textbox having 'date' will get datetimepicker. In that case, whenever I will add a new textbox with id having 'date', I won't need to change the existing jquery code again and again.

Comment: $( "input[id$='date']") like an ends with selector

Comment: Are you sure that all those elements don't have a certain class taken and initialized automatically by `$.datetimepicker`?

Comment: Exactly, now I know the error. The form id was validateForm. Since it has 'date' in its id, it was also having datetimepicker. Now how can I restrict to have input type=textbox having id='date'?

Comment: why not you assign class date and initialize datetimepicker on class $(".date").datetimepicker();

Answer (score 0):

```
Ideally using class is best instead of id in this case.

<input type="text" id="title" > # don't apply to this
<input type="text" id="sdate" class="my-class">
<input type="text" id="edate" class="my-class">
<input type="text" id="pdate" class="my-class">
```

and jquery will be just

```
$('.my-class').datetimepicker({
   formatTime:'H:i:s',
   formatDate:'Y-m-d',
   dayOfWeekStart : 1,
   lang:'en'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign common class to inputs where you want datetimepicker and initialize using class, this will help you to restrict only inputs with classes

```
$(".date").datetimepicker();
```

assuming your input have common class date.

Hope this helps :)